# MaterialUI: Box loses its background on reload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, next.js

I'm trying to apply a background color to a [Box component from Material UI](https://material-ui.com/components/box/). It does work until I reload the page: after reload, the background color is lost. I use Next.js to create my app.

However, the color reappears whenever I add another component to the page. So it seems the reload from Next.js makes the background color comes back.

Here is the code:

```
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";

export default function Test() {
    return (
        <Box bgcolor="primary.main" align="center">
            <Typography>Test</Typography>
        </Box>
    );
}
```

And here is a short GIF showing the result:
[image: Box background color is lost on reload]

Comment: it doesnt get lost it just gets delayed. by looking at the docs https://material-ui.com/components/box/#box bgcolor is not a property which you can pass down

Comment: They do use the bgcolor property in the doc: https://material-ui.com/system/palette/#background-color. However, when I copy their example I don't end up with the result they show, the background color is not displayed...